# Errors when loading scikit-image: "ImportError: cannot import name _fblas"

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, numpy, scipy

I am using python 2.7 on Ubuntu 12.04.  I have been upgrading my python libraries with pip, and using pip (as root) to install numpy, scipy, scikit-image, matplotlib.  However, when I attempt to load scikit-image:

```
import skimage.io as io
```

I obtain a slew of error messages, of which the last few lines are:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/__init__.py in <module>()
    155 from .linalg_version import linalg_version as __version__
    156 
--> 157 from .misc import *
    158 from .basic import *
    159 from .decomp import *

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/misc.py in <module>()
      3 import numpy as np
      4 from numpy.linalg import LinAlgError
----> 5 from . import blas
      6 
      7 __all__ = ['LinAlgError', 'norm']

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/blas.py in <module>()
    129 import numpy as _np
    130 
--> 131 from scipy.linalg import _fblas
    132 try:
    133     from scipy.linalg import _cblas

ImportError: cannot import name _fblas
```

It's possible (indeed, likely) that pip is putting packages in a directory where my installed python can't find them, and I might have a mismatch of python from the Ubuntu repositories, and as installed by pip.

In which case - what is the easiest way to fix this problem - or, even better - how can I install a brand new python with all the trimmings, and which has access to the latest versions of the numpy, scipy, matplotlib, scikit-* libraries?

Comment: Sorted!  I reinstalled both ipython and ipython-qtconsole using pip, which overwrote the versions installed from Ubuntu repositories.  Now everything's "on the same page", and it all works well.  Sorry to bother you.